# Listing all the comments received on the videos I uploaded on YouTube

Tags: youtube, comments

Is there any way to list all the comments received on the videos I uploaded on YouTube?  On https://www.youtube.com/comments it seems that I can only get the list of "published" comments, which is only a small subset of all comments.

Basically I am looking for a way to moderate those comments efficiently (list all comments received + an easy way to remove the ones I don't want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to list all the comments received on the videos you uploaded on YouTube.